# miniconda and Travis, what does hash -r do?

Tags: python, anaconda, travis-ci, conda, miniconda

In [Conda's manual for Travis integration](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/use-conda-with-travis-ci.html), what does `hash -r` do and is it necessary?

Comment: Carl, that's really a Linux question not a programming question. Check out: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: No, I consider CI equally programming and OS related (e.g. DevOps). Travis is striving to be OS agnostic too (though there's obviously still a heavy focus on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash` is a bash builtin. `hash -r` will rescan the `$PATH` for available executable commands, so Bash knows what to execute when you type a command name.

According to `man bash`, if type in a command, Bash will first search its internal data structure for which command to execute. If that fails, it will make a search in the `$PATH`.

It seems to me that this call to `hash -r` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, you seem to be right, Travis builds seem to work without it.

Comment: I think the purpose of running `hash -r` is to be extra cautious. Since they edit `$PATH`, strange things could happen if your Travis script had previously called an executable that should now be called using the version installed by conda.

Comment: If you install a package or script, and add an `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/package", you need to run `hash -r` to use your installed scripts. I needed this when I installed miniconda and wanted to run the "conda" command